# Google charts - ComboChart - bars and candlesticks

Tags: charts, google-visualization, bar-chart, candlestick-chart

I try create ComboChart where are bars and series of waterfall(candlestick) chart.
I dont know how to create data input for this.
Candlestick needs format like:

```
['Mon', 20, 28, 38, 45],
['Tue', 31, 38, 55, 66],
['Wed', 50, 55, 77, 80],
['Thu', 77, 77, 66, 50],
['Fri', 68, 66, 22, 15]
```

and bars in my case:

```
['name', 'value', { role: 'style' }],
['test1', 8, '#00f'], 
['test2', 10,'#000'],
['test3', 19,'#f00'],
```

Is it even possible to do it ? Join bars and candlesticks ?

Comment: can you share how your output will look like?

Comment: Hi, ofc, there is example http://imgur.com/GSdp0Yx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use the `series` option to control the *chart type* for each series
   each series is represented by a column, or a set of columns, in the data
   starting with the first column that is not the x-axis or a column role

*example*: the columns for the chart you describe might resemble the following...

```
"cols":[
  // x-axis
  {"label":"Category","type":"string"},

  // bar series -- 0
  {"label":"Bar 0","type":"number"},

  // bar series -- 1
  {"label":"Bar 1","type":"number"},

  // waterfall series -- 2
  {"label":"WF 2 - Bottom 1","type":"number"},
  {"label":"WF 2 - Bottom 2","type":"number"},
  {"label":"WF 2 - Top 1","type":"number"},
  {"label":"WF 2 - Top 2","type":"number"},
  {"role":"style","type":"string","p":{"role":"style"}},

  // bar series -- 3
  {"label":"Bar 3","type":"number"}
],
```

the candlestick chart requires 4 columns, in the above example, a style column role is also used,
as such, all five columns are considered part of series number 2

---

2. when building data for a [combochart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart#data-format),
   use `null` for the series values,
   when they do not coincide with the same x-axis value

*example data*:

```
"rows":[
  // bar (series 0 & 1) data
  {"c":[{"v":"YTD"},{"v":14807893.054},{"v":11684139.912},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]},
  {"c":[{"v":"Last Year"},{"v":16307893.054},{"v":20684139.912},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]},

  // waterfall (series 2) data
  {"c":[{"v":"Budget"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":22707893.613},{"v":22707893.613},{"v":"#007fff"},{"v":null}]},
  {"c":[{"v":"Contract Labor"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":22707893.613},{"v":22707893.613},{"v":22534350.429},{"v":22534350.429},{"v":"#1e8449"},{"v":null}]},
  {"c":[{"v":"Contract Non Labor"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":22534350.429},{"v":22534350.429},{"v":22930956.493},{"v":22930956.493},{"v":"#922b21"},{"v":null}]},
  {"c":[{"v":"Matls & Equip"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":22930956.493},{"v":22930956.493},{"v":22800059.612},{"v":22800059.612},{"v":"#1e8449"},{"v":null}]},
  {"c":[{"v":"Other"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":22800059.612},{"v":22800059.612},{"v":21993391.103},{"v":21993391.103},{"v":"#1e8449"},{"v":null}]},
  {"c":[{"v":"Labor"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":21993391.103},{"v":21993391.103},{"v":21546003.177999996},{"v":21546003.177999996},{"v":"#1e8449"},{"v":null}]},
  {"c":[{"v":"Travel"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":21546003.177999996},{"v":21546003.177999996},{"v":21533258.930999994},{"v":21533258.930999994},{"v":"#1e8449"},{"v":null}]},
  {"c":[{"v":"Training"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":21533258.930999994},{"v":21533258.930999994},{"v":21550964.529999994},{"v":21550964.529999994},{"v":"#922b21"},{"v":null}]},
  {"c":[{"v":"Actual"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":21550964.52999999},{"v":21550964.52999999},{"v":"#007fff"},{"v":null}]},

  // bar (series 3) data
  {"c":[{"v":"FCST"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":16182561.25}]}
]
```

---

3. following is a working example of a combo chart with bars and candlesticks

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawChart();
    $(window).resize(drawChart);
  },
  packages:['corechart', 'table']
});

function drawChart() {
  var dataChart = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    "cols":[
      // x-axis
      {"label":"Category","type":"string"},

      // bar series -- 0
      {"label":"Bar 0","type":"number"},

      // bar series -- 1
      {"label":"Bar 1","type":"number"},

      // waterfall series -- 2
      {"label":"WF 2 - Bottom 1","type":"number"},
      {"label":"WF 2 - Bottom 2","type":"number"},
      {"label":"WF 2 - Top 1","type":"number"},
      {"label":"WF 2 - Top 2","type":"number"},
      {"role":"style","type":"string","p":{"role":"style"}},

      // bar series -- 3
      {"label":"Bar 3","type":"number"}
    ],
    "rows":[
      // bar (series 0 & 1) data
      {"c":[{"v":"YTD"},{"v":14807893.054},{"v":11684139.912},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Last Year"},{"v":16307893.054},{"v":20684139.912},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]},

      // waterfall (series 2) data
      {"c":[{"v":"Budget"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":22707893.613},{"v":22707893.613},{"v":"#007fff"},{"v":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Contract Labor"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":22707893.613},{"v":22707893.613},{"v":22534350.429},{"v":22534350.429},{"v":"#1e8449"},{"v":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Contract Non Labor"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":22534350.429},{"v":22534350.429},{"v":22930956.493},{"v":22930956.493},{"v":"#922b21"},{"v":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Matls & Equip"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":22930956.493},{"v":22930956.493},{"v":22800059.612},{"v":22800059.612},{"v":"#1e8449"},{"v":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Other"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":22800059.612},{"v":22800059.612},{"v":21993391.103},{"v":21993391.103},{"v":"#1e8449"},{"v":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Labor"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":21993391.103},{"v":21993391.103},{"v":21546003.177999996},{"v":21546003.177999996},{"v":"#1e8449"},{"v":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Travel"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":21546003.177999996},{"v":21546003.177999996},{"v":21533258.930999994},{"v":21533258.930999994},{"v":"#1e8449"},{"v":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Training"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":21533258.930999994},{"v":21533258.930999994},{"v":21550964.529999994},{"v":21550964.529999994},{"v":"#922b21"},{"v":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Actual"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":21550964.52999999},{"v":21550964.52999999},{"v":"#007fff"},{"v":null}]},

      // bar (series 3) data
      {"c":[{"v":"FCST"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":16182561.25}]}
    ]
  });

  var comboChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'ComboChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    dataTable: dataChart,
    options: {
      animation: {
        duration: 1500,
        easing: 'inAndOut',
        startup: true
      },
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      bar: {
        group: {
          width: '85%'
        }
      },
      chartArea: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        bottom: 42,
        height: '100%',
        left: 60,
        top: 24,
        width: '100%'
      },
      hAxis: {
        textStyle: {
          fontSize: 12
        }
      },
      height: 400,
      legend: 'none',
      seriesType: 'bars',
      series: {
        2: {
          type: 'candlesticks'
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        isHtml: true,
        trigger: 'both'
      },
      vAxis: {
        format: 'short',
        textStyle: {
          color: '#616161'
        },
        viewWindow: {
          min: 10000000,
          max: 24000000
        }
      },
      width: '100%'
    }
  });
  comboChart.draw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

*note*: you'll notice when running the snippet in *full page* mode,
the chart doesn't do a very good job of aligning the x-axis labels
you *may* be able to manipulate the options to get them to align better,
but it *will* take some manipulation...

---

4. you might have better results, creating three separate charts, side-by-side
   just need to make sure each has the same `vAxis` values,
   you could hide the extra `vAxis` labels if needed, etc...
   again, *manipulation* is required

*example*: snippet displayed best in *full page* mode...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawChart();
    $(window).resize(drawChart);
  },
  packages:['corechart', 'table']
});

function drawChart() {
  var dataBar0 = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    "cols":[
      {"label":"Category","type":"string"},
      {"label":"Bar 0","type":"number"},
      {"label":"Bar 1","type":"number"}
    ],
    "rows":[
      // bar 0 data
      {"c":[{"v":"YTD"},{"v":22807893.054},{"v":18684139.912}]}
    ]
  });

  var barChart0 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'ColumnChart',
    containerId: 'bar_chart_0',
    dataTable: dataBar0,
    options: {
      animation: {
        duration: 1500,
        easing: 'inAndOut',
        startup: true
      },
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      bar: {
        gap: 20,
        width: 60
      },
      chartArea: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      },
      height: 400,
      legend: 'none',
      theme: 'maximized',
      tooltip: {
        isHtml: true,
        trigger: 'both'
      },
      vAxis: {
        format: 'short',
        viewWindow: {
          min: 10000000,
          max: 24000000
        }
      }
    }
  });
  barChart0.draw();

  var dataWF0 = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    "cols":[
      {"label":"Category","type":"string"},
      {"label":"WF 2 - Bottom 1","type":"number"},
      {"label":"WF 2 - Bottom 2","type":"number"},
      {"label":"WF 2 - Top 1","type":"number"},
      {"label":"WF 2 - Top 2","type":"number"},
      {"role":"style","type":"string","p":{"role":"style"}}
    ],
    "rows":[
      {"c":[{"v":"Budget"},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":22707893.613},{"v":22707893.613},{"v":"#007fff"}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Other"},{"v":22800059.612},{"v":22800059.612},{"v":21993391.103},{"v":21993391.103},{"v":"#1e8449"}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Labor"},{"v":21993391.103},{"v":21993391.103},{"v":21546003.177999996},{"v":21546003.177999996},{"v":"#1e8449"}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Travel"},{"v":21546003.177999996},{"v":21546003.177999996},{"v":21533258.930999994},{"v":21533258.930999994},{"v":"#1e8449"}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Training"},{"v":21533258.930999994},{"v":21533258.930999994},{"v":21550964.529999994},{"v":21550964.529999994},{"v":"#922b21"}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Actual"},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":21550964.52999999},{"v":21550964.52999999},{"v":"#007fff"}]}
    ]
  });

  var wfChart0 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'CandlestickChart',
    containerId: 'wf_chart_0',
    dataTable: dataWF0,
    options: {
      animation: {
        duration: 1500,
        easing: 'inAndOut',
        startup: true
      },
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      bar: {
        gap: 20,
        width: 60
      },
      chartArea: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
      },
      height: 400,
      legend: 'none',
      theme: 'maximized',
      tooltip: {
        isHtml: true,
        trigger: 'both'
      },
      vAxis: {
        format: 'short',
        viewWindow: {
          min: 10000000,
          max: 24000000
        }
      },
      width: '100%'
    }
  });
  wfChart0.draw();

  var dataBar1 = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    "cols":[
      {"label":"Category","type":"string"},
      {"label":"Bar 0","type":"number"},
      {"label":"Bar 1","type":"number"}
    ],
    "rows":[
      // bar 0 data
      {"c":[{"v":"YTD"},{"v":20807893.054},{"v":19684139.912}]}
    ]
  });

  var barChart1 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'ColumnChart',
    containerId: 'bar_chart_1',
    dataTable: dataBar1,
    options: {
      animation: {
        duration: 1500,
        easing: 'inAndOut',
        startup: true
      },
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      bar: {
        gap: 20,
        width: 60
      },
      chartArea: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      },
      height: 400,
      legend: 'none',
      theme: 'maximized',
      tooltip: {
        isHtml: true,
        trigger: 'both'
      },
      vAxis: {
        format: 'short',
        viewWindow: {
          min: 10000000,
          max: 24000000
        }
      }
    }
  });
  barChart1.draw();
}
```

```css
.max-chart {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="max-chart" id="bar_chart_0"></div>
<div class="max-chart" id="wf_chart_0"></div>
<div class="max-chart" id="bar_chart_1"></div>
```